Does the vindictive bastard paladin get spells?
I've been looking up and down to double check and I can't find anything confirming it. Some say they do because nothing on their new kit states otherwise, others say they don't due to being an EX class, can someone help me out?

A vindictive bastard is, by definition, an ex-paladin:

This archetype can be taken by an ex-[paladin] immediately upon becoming an ex-[paladin], regardless of character level, replacing some or all of the lost class abilities. […]
[…] Upon [atoning and becoming a true paladin again], she immediately loses this archetype and regains her original class (and archetype, if she had one).

(About ex-class archetypes)
Ex-paladins don’t have paladin spells:

Ex-Paladins
A paladin who [does certain things] loses all paladin spells […]

(Paladin class description)
This means that vindictive bastard doesn’t need to say anything about spells: the ex-paladin who becomes one has already lost them. An ex-paladin archetype could grant new spellcasting, but vindictive bastard doesn’t (can’t really cite this, there’s just no feature of the archetype that includes any spells). Nor does it provide any other replacement for the lost “Spells” class feature—and that’s just fine: the definition of ex-class archetypes specifically says that such archetypes may replace only “some of the lost class abilities.”
So no, vindictive bastards do not get spells (from their vindictive bastard ex-paladin levels, anyway).
